# Updating Mysql Database Aruba

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, aruba

I'm facing a big problem folks,

My goal is to have a

- Joomla Website that show some data from a database
- i want to update the database with queries (not phpmyadmin!)

What do i have

- Website with a couple of Local Mysql DB(not accessible from client tho)
- Amaz. AWS Database service

Too bad the hosting company (aruba) BLOCK the traffic from different DATA sources that are not their. I subscribed also to Amazon AWS for have a DB accessible by anyone but isnt helping much.
I have to find a way to update the website db in any automatic way, or even just mirror an other accessible DB.
I couldn't have thought any better, anyone  feel like help me ?

Comment: Um, find a different host?

Comment: Since i've been using Top Tier host, i'm not sure that other will have different policies. But if anyone have any suggestion i'm wide open to suggestion.

Comment: In agree with  Strawberry.